# Failing to understand the observer pattern, where is the decoupling

Tags: design-patterns, observer-pattern

I'm reading head first design patterns, and they are trying to explain the observer pattern.
If i understood correctly the purpose of this pattern is to decouple the observing objects from the data itself.

It is done by inheriting from IObserver and having an "Update" method, and then registering to some interface that should call my update when something is changed.

But after something is changed i still need to object itself to check what exactly changed, so where is the Decoupling ?

In the example i have in the book they are making several different weather widgets that are dependent on a data that comes from bunch of sensors. 
They are trying to decouple the widgets from the sensors, but as you can see they have a direct pointer from every widget directly to the data from the sensors (it's written in the bottom of the page), so there is actually no decoupling at all.

Am i missing something ?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Observer pattern decouples observer from the observed.  It does not decouple the Observer from the data generated due to observation.**

So, in case of this discussion, multiple types of displays (Observers) for Weather Data has been decoupled from the instrument that is monitoring the weather data (Subject).

**In order to verify whether this decoupling is for real or not, you need to ask the question "If I have to add one more observer, how many classes I will have to change to add the new observer?"** -  And in this case answer is zero, as you are just adding a new observer class which will register itself with the Subject.  And there will not be single line of code change in either the "Subject" or rest of the "Observers".

Observer design pattern, in a way, helps you in achieving Open-Closed Principle (OCP). As per this principle, a class should be "Open for extension" but "Closed for modification".

Hope this clarifies!

Answer (score 1):

In your book's example, effectively the Observer objects are coupled with the Subject object.

The coupled is originated for the fact that the Observers have to know the information that is stored in the Subject.

However, this pattern can be implemented in different ways, so you can avoid this coupling. The easyest way is to pass the information as parameters when you invoke the method that informs to the Observers that something has changed. (this is called "push" data)

According to your example the method's signature could be:

> update (int temperature, int humidity, int pressure)

Answer (score 0):

this design pattern is usually used for registering for events, what register for that event is independent from the event itself, but must adjhere to a given interface, when the event takes place every actual implementation of the observers that are registered for that event gets notified by calling `object.update()`.

As probably you can see the decoupling is in the sense that you could give your library that does and handles events, and the user of your library could register for them, you will call their code, possibly without knowing what that code does.

is that more *obscure* now?